# Is there an Emacs package for html escaping?

Tags: html, emacs

Example:

```
<p>Um diese App verwenden zu können, benötigen Sie JavaScript.</p>
```

Should be replaced by:

```
<p>Um diese App verwenden zu k&ouml;nnen, ben&ouml;tigen Sie JavaScript.</p>
```

Is there an existing function or package that performs this kind of replacement on a region?

Comment: Quick googling is slightly discouraging.  There is mounds of code to *decode* entities in HTML, but precious little to go in the opposite direction. `w3m.el` contains an entity database which should be handy as a starting point; I guess various HTML and XML editing modes will contain something similar.

Comment: If you don't require *named* entities, replacing `[^ -~]` with `(format "&#%d;" (int-to-string (string-to-char char)))` should be a breeze.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Named entities will make it invalid XHTML, if that happens to be an issue. These days unicode will make it back and forth across the great majority of tool chains with no problem.

Comment: I cobbled together a half-witted attempt which I could not get to work. It could only support Latin-1 because that's what's available in `sgml-mode.el` which I used as my platform.  Maybe somebody else can pick up where I left off and finish it.  I don't understand character tables well enough, apparently. For example, it turns `"¤"` into `"&dollar;"` which is obviously incorrect. http://pastebin.com/cVQUTS9s

Comment: @torazaburo Well, at my workplace, we have the coding standard to use ASCII. Overall, I think it is reasonable when working with JSPs, as it keeps things simple. Otherwise, there is always the possibility to mix up ISO-8859-1 and UTF8, which can lead to subtle bugs. Anyway, you have a point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132/are-named-entities-in-html-still-necessary-in-the-age-of-unicode-aware-browsers#25173

Comment: Turns out newer versions of `sgml-mode` have `sgml-name-8bit-mode` which toggles whether it uses entities or literal characters.

Comment: I just discovered an `sgml` input method which allows you to input entity escapes and have them turned into literals.  Another place where you could find a reasonable catalog of entity names already installed on your system for easy access from your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited after comments, thanks.

Download file html2uml.el here:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~a-roehler/s-x-emacs-werkstatt/trunk/view/head:/html2uml.el

Please file reports WRT wrong or missing entities here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/s-x-emacs-werkstatt

Code for now:

```
(defvar ar-html2uml
  '(
    ("&nbsp;" " ")
    ("&iexcl;" "¡")
    ("&cent;" "¢")
    ("&pound;" "£")
    ("&curren;" "\x{00A4}")
    ("&yen;" "¥")
    ("&brvbar;" "\x{00A6}")
    ("&sect;" "§")
    ("&uml;" "\x{00A8}")
    ("&copy;" "©")
    ("&ordf;" "ª")
    ("&laquo;" "«")
    ("&not;" "¬")
    ("&shy;" "­")
    ("&reg;" "®")
    ("&macr;" "¯")
    ("&deg;" "°")
    ("&plusmn;" "±")
    ("&sup2;" "²")
    ("&sup3;" "³")
    ("&acute;" "\x{00B4}")
    ("&micro;" "µ")
    ("&para;" "¶")
    ("&middot;" "·")
    ("&cedil;" "\x{00B8}")
    ("&sup1;" "¹")
    ("&ordm;" "º")
    ("&raquo;" "»")
    ("&frac14;" "\x{00BC}")
    ("&frac12;" "\x{00BD}")
    ("&frac34;" "\x{00BE}")
    ("&iquest;" "¿")
    ("&Agrave;" "À")
    ("&Aacute;" "Á")
    ("&Acirc;" "Â")
    ("&Atilde;" "Ã")
    ("&Auml;" "Ä")
    ("&Aring;" "Å")
    ("&AElig;" "Æ")
    ("&Ccedil;" "Ç")
    ("&Egrave;" "È")
    ("&Eacute;" "É")
    ("&Ecirc;" "Ê")
    ("&Euml;" "Ë")
    ("&Igrave;" "Ì")
    ("&Iacute;" "Í")
    ("&Icirc;" "Î")
    ("&Iuml;" "Ï")
    ("&ETH;" "Ð")
    ("&Ntilde;" "Ñ")
    ("&Ograve;" "Ò")
    ("&Oacute;" "Ó")
    ("&Ocirc;" "Ô")
    ("&Otilde;" "Õ")
    ("&Ouml;" "Ö")
    ("&times;" "×")
    ("&Oslash;" "Ø")
    ("&Ugrave;" "Ù")
    ("&Uacute;" "Ú")
    ("&Ucirc;" "Û")
    ("&Uuml;" "Ü")
    ("&Yacute;" "Ý")
    ("&THORN;" "Þ")
    ("&szlig;" "ß")
    ("&agrave;" "à")
    ("&aacute;" "á")
    ("&acirc;" "â")
    ("&atilde;" "ã")
    ("&auml;" "ä")
    ("&aring;" "å")
    ("&aelig;" "æ")
    ("&ccedil;" "ç")
    ("&egrave;" "è")
    ("&eacute;" "é")
    ("&ecirc;" "ê")
    ("&euml;" "ë")
    ("&igrave;" "ì")
    ("&iacute;" "í")
    ("&icirc;" "î")
    ("&iuml;" "ï")
    ("&eth;" "ð")
    ("&ntilde;" "ñ")
    ("&ograve;" "ò")
    ("&oacute;" "ó")
    ("&ocirc;" "ô")
    ("&otilde;" "õ")
    ("&ouml;" "ö")
    ("\&Ouml;" "Ö")
    ("&divide;" "÷")
    ("&oslash;" "ø")
    ("&ugrave;" "ù")
    ("&uacute;" "ú")
    ("&ucirc;" "û")
    ("&uuml;" "ü")
    ("&yacute;" "ý")
    ("&thorn;" "þ")
    ("&yuml;" "ÿ")
    ))

(defun ar-uml2html ()
  "Translate chars into html entities"
  (interactive "*")
  (let ((liste ar-html2uml)
        case-fold-search erg)
    (dolist (ele liste)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward (cadr ele) nil t 1)
        (setq erg (car ele))
        ;; Replacing with code starting from & upcases
        ;; Emacs bug?
        (replace-match "")
        (insert erg)))))

(defun ar-html2uml ()
  "Translate html entities into text"
  (interactive "*")
  (let ((liste ar-html2uml))
    (dolist (ele liste)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward (car ele) nil t 1)
        (replace-match "")
        (insert (cadr ele))))))
```

Comment: This performs the opposite mapping from what the OP as requesting.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen Provided a command mapping inverse - as requested. Case sensitiveness was already listed, but replacement didn't work as expected. Fixed - See comment in source.